# PHP MySQL Converting names to ID's and inserting is returning NULL values

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form where the user can input the name (combined string of first and last names) of a member, student and/or instructor. They also input other data irrelevant to this question. This is all inserted into a table called `games`. A table called `members`, `students` and `instructors` already exists with fields including `id`, `first_name` and `last_name` for each. All the required foreign key constraints are in order. So when the user submits the form, I only want the corresponding id of the member, student and/or instructor to be inserted, not their name(s).

I have the following code, and it successfully submits all information besides the id of the member, student and/or instructor, which appear in the record as NULL.

If anyone could highlight the issue here I would greatly appreciate it.

Form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="action.php" method="post">
        <p>
    <p>
        <label for="instructor_name">Instructor:</label>
        <input type="text" name="instructor_name" id="instructor_name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="student_name">Student:</label>
        <input type="text" name="student_name" id="student_name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="member_name">Member:</label>
        <input type="text" name="member_name" id="member_name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="exercises">Exercises:</label>
        <input type="text" name="exercises" id="exercises">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="auth_by">Authorised By:</label>
        <input type="text" name="auth_by" id="auth_by">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="auth_duration">Authorisation Duration:</label>
        <input type="text" name="auth_duration" id="auth_duration">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Action:

```
<?php

// connection information
include 'pdo_config.php';

try {
// new pdo connection
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);

// post data
$member_name = $_POST['member_name'];
$exercises = $_POST['exercises'];
$auth_by = $_POST['auth_by'];
$auth_duration = $_POST['auth_duration'];
$student_name = $_POST['student_name'];
$instructor_name = $_POST['instructor_name'];

// get corresponding id's of names
$name_m = explode(" ", $member_name);
$first_name_m = $name_m[0];
$last_name_m = $name_m[1];
$statement1 = $conn->prepare("SELECT member_id FROM tbl_members WHERE first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name");
$statement1->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name_m, ':last_name' => $last_name_m));
$row1 = $statement1->fetch();
$member_id = $row1['member_id'];

$name_i = explode(" ", $instructor_name);
$first_name_i = $name_i[0];
$last_name_i = $name_i[1];
$statement2 = $conn->prepare("SELECT instructor_id FROM tbl_instructors WHERE first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name");
$statement2->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name_i, ':last_name' => $last_name_i));
$row2 = $statement2->fetch();
$instructor_id = $row2['instructor_id'];

$name_s = explode(" ", $student_name);
$first_name_s = $name_s[0];
$last_name_s = $name_s[1];
$statement3 = $conn->prepare("SELECT student_id FROM tbl_students WHERE first_name = :first_name AND last_name = :last_name");
$statement3->execute(array(':first_name' => $first_name_s, ':last_name' => $last_name_s));
$row3 = $statement3->fetch();
$student_id = $row3['student_id'];

// prepare statements and bind parameters
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tbl_games (member_id, exercises, auth_by, auth_duration, student_id, instructor_id) VALUES (:member_id, :exercises, :auth_by, :auth_duration, :student_id, :instructor_id)");

$stmt->bindParam(':member_id', $member_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':exercises', $exercises);
$stmt->bindParam(':auth_by', $auth_by);
$stmt->bindParam(':auth_duration', $auth_duration);
$stmt->bindParam(':student_id', $student_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':instructor_id', $instructor_id);

// execute statements
$stmt->execute();

// success or error message
echo "New record created successfully";
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;

?>
```

Comment: If you're wanting to use POST arrays as multi-dimensional, then you need to treat your inputs as arrays. I.e.: `name="xxx[]"` which seems to be the case here. Otherwise, don't.

Comment: When you debug this, what are the values of the variables for the IDs you're inserting?  Are any records returned by the `SELECT` queries at all?  What are the values you're using in *those* queries, and do any records match those values *exactly*?  (Additionally, it seems kind of weird to be storing *very* similar data in three separate tables and requiring all these different queries in the first place.)

Comment: Obviously only answering to "answers" rather than "comments". Ok, I'm out of here. I spent enough time looking at this.

Comment: Why three seperate queries? Combine them with union (and add an attribute to identify the source).

Comment: @David In the testing I've done, the record (and ID) exist for each corresponding name, and the data was exact, so there is no reason why it wouldn't work. And didn't mention it but the three tables don't contain entirely similar data, for example, `members` has a `membership` field where instructors do not. So they had to have unique tables.

Comment: @sinesine: They don't *have* to have unique tables, you could have a single "users" or "persons" super-table which has separate detail tables.  But that's unrelated to the problem so no big deal.  For the testing, what has your actual debugging confirmed?  Don't just assume that everything *should* work, actually debug it.

Comment: @Fred -ii- Sorry, I'm still trying to understand what you meant. Why would I treat the input as an array if it isn't one?

Comment: @David Would you suggest I echo the result of the `SELECT` queries?

Answer (score 1):

You may enter a member that does not exist and must be validated.

Or load combo with members first, and user select id from combo and send to server id member.

Comment: I know a combobox would be a lot easier, but would it be practical for dynamic and large numbers of members/students/instructors?